# how to load first x bytes from URL with Java / Scala?

Tags: java, scala, url, urlconnection

I want to read the first x bytes from a `java.net.URLConnection` (although I'm not forced to use this class - other suggestions welcome).

My code looks like this:

```
val head = new Array[Byte](2000)  
new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream).read(head)
IOUtils.toString(new ByteArrayInputStream(head), charset)
```

It works, but does this code load only the first 2000 bytes from the network?

**Next trial**

As 'JB Nizet' said it is not useful to use a buffered input stream, so I tried it with an `InputStreamReader`:

```
val head = new Array[Char](2000)  
new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream, charset).read(head)
new String(head)
```

This code may be better, but the load times are about the same. So does this procedure limit the transferred bytes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`read(Reader, char[])`](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20char%5b%5d%29) from Apache Commons IO. Just pass a 2000-character buffer to it and it will fill it with as many characters as possible, up to 2000.

Be sure you understand the objections in the other answers/comments, in particular:

- Don't use `Buffered...` wrappers, it goes against your intentions.
- If you read textual data, then use a `Reader` to read 2000 *characters* instead of `InputStream` reading 2000 *bytes*. The proper procedure would be to determine the character encoding from the headers of a response (`Content-Type`) and set that encoding into `InputStreamReader`.
- Calling plain `read(char[])` on a `Reader` will not fully fill the array you give to it. It can read as little as one character no matter how big the array is!
- Don't forget to close the reader afterwards.

Other than that, I'd strongly recommend you to use [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) in favor of `java.net.URLConnection`. It's much more flexible.

---

**Edit:** To understand the difference between `Reader.read` and `IOUtils.read`, it's worth examining the source of the latter:

```
public static int read(Reader input, char[] buffer,
                       int offset, int length)
    throws IOException
{
    if (length < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length must not be negative: " + length);
    }
    int remaining = length;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        int location = length - remaining;
        int count = input.read(buffer, offset + location, remaining);
        if (EOF == count) { // EOF
            break;
        }
        remaining -= count;
    }
    return length - remaining;
}
```

Since `Reader.read` can read less characters than a given length (we only know it's at least 1 and at most the length), we need to iterate calling it until we get the amount we want.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, my second trial should work. The content type is determined before I read any characters.

Comment: Basically yes, but you have to use `IOUtils.read` instead of calling `read` on a `Reader` directly. This is very important. `Reader.read` only guarantees you that it reads at least 1 character and at most the array you give to it. So in many cases it won't read enough data even if it is available. On the other hand, `IOUtils.read` guarantees you that it will read as many characters as possible.

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn't. It could read up to 8192 bytes (the deault buffer size of `BufferedInputStream`). It could also read 0 bytes, or any number of bytes between 0 and 2000, since you don't check the number of bytes that have actually been read, and which is returned by the `read()` method.

And finally, depending on the value of charset, and of the actual charset used by the HTTP response, this could return an incorrect string, or a String truncated in the middle of a multi-byte character. You should use a Reader to read text.

I suggest you read the [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html).

Comment: +1 As the TCP buffer at each end is likely to be a total of 128 KB or more, the server could send this much before the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that potential string problems. But how can I limit the bytes fetched from the network? As far as I understand `new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream, 2000)` would not be the solution.

Comment: Why do you want to buffer your stream, since you know exactly how many bytes you want to read, and read them in one go (if available)?